# How to detect a particular type of cycle in a directed graph?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, directed-graph

I am using [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) to analyse some directed graphs and their properties, but I'm stuck with a particular example. Let's consider a simple digraph:

```
  1 -----> 2
 /          \
F            M
 \          /
  3 -----> 4
```

This graph can be constructed with `networkx`:

```py
graph = networkx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from([("F", 1), (1, 2), (2, "M"), ("F", 3), (3, 4), (4, "M")])
```

Let's call the node `F` the *fork node* and `M` the *merge node*. All edges are unidirectional, and go from the left to the right.

I would like to detect a particular case of cycles that start within the "fork section" (i.e. between the fork and the merge nodes) but end outside of it. Let's call them *invalid cycles*. We can create such a cycle by adding an edge from node `4` to node `F`:

```
    1 -----> 2
   /           \
  F             M
/  \           /
\   3 -----> 4
 \          /
  <---------
```

The new edge forms a *feedback loop* that starts **between** the nodes `F` and `M`, but ends **outside** of these nodes.

The two following examples, on the contrary, are valid:

```
The feedback loop starts and ends outside nodes `F` and `M`:
    1 -----> 2
   /           \
  F             M
/  \           / \
\   3 -----> 4   /
 \              /
  <-------------

The feedback loop starts and ends between nodes `F` and `M`:
  O -----> O
 /           \
F             M
 \           /
  O -----> O
   \      /
    <-----
```

My main question is: **how can I detect this kind of cycles?** I don't need to retrieve the nodes part of the cycle, I only need to know that the graph has such a cycle. My graphs are not very large so I'm not concerned with performance.

Auxiliary questions: How to find the merge node corresponding to a given fork node in a potentially larger graph where there are multiple forks? Is there a name for such cycles?  Do these cycles have some special properties?

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd to talk about the start and end of a cycle.  Cycles go around and around, with no start and no end.

I think what you mean is: cycles that contain some of the vertices between F and M, but neither of F nor M.

If I am correct about that then the algorithm is straighforward.

```
- Find all cycles in the graph
- LOOP C over all cycles
  - IF C contains some of the vertices between F and M, but neither of F nor M.
     - Add C to output.
```

Comment: In the example case, the cycles do contain F.

Comment: You are right.  Please define the cycles you want to detect in some way that does not involve starts or ends - cycles do not have those things.

Comment: If you do, then the algorithm you need will likely become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find all paths from F to M.
2. Let S be the set of nodes G ≠ M for which there is an edge F → G in such a path.
3. Delete M and all its edges from the graph.
4. For each G in S, find all paths from G to F.

The above algorithm finds every such cycle. If you just want to test whether or not the graph has *any* such cycle, then instead of step 4 you can do a breadth-first search in the [reverse graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph), from F until you find any node in S.

Comment: Do you have some ideas about how to find `M` when I know `F`?